# how to create a string from a txt file

Tags: c++, io

I am attempting to take a txt file and create a string from it but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

I have tried to use the `getline` string function but it does not create a proper string in the way I have used it.

```
ifstream inFile("somefile.txt");
string mystring;

while (getline(inFile, mystring)) {

    cout << mystring << endl;
}
```

The end goal of my program is to read a .txt file line by line and edit each line so it is 100 char wide. This first part seems to be the only place where I am having an issue at the moment.

Comment: getline() just extracts a line from the file stream into a string variable. Then you can use that string. In your case you could write a function to format that string and stream it into another file.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a proper string"? What is the output of your program? What do you expect it to be? Have you checked that `infile` is opening without errors? Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be due to the stream object could not find or open the file. Try checking if the `inFile` is good or valid.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;
using std::string;
using std::endl;


int main() {
    ifstream inFile("example.txt");
    string mystring;
    if( inFile ) // or inFile.good()
    {
        while (getline(inFile, mystring)) 
        {
            cout << mystring << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open File\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my true problem was not having the txt file in the correct directory, but you were correct